# App spends too much RAM when I do large loops

Tags: java, android, ram

I have this code and I want to do the same but spending less ram. Any idea to set a image loader in each of 300 `ImageView` that I generate or something similar to solve this issue?

```
DisplayMetrics lDisplayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int widthPixels = lDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;
for (int getDrawables = 0; getDrawables < 300; getDrawables++)
{
    final ImageView icoView = new ImageView(ImageEditor.this);
    icoView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("icon_"+getDrawables, "drawable", getPackageName()));
    icoView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(widthPixels/7,widthPixels/7));
    gridlayout.addView(icoView);
    int idGen = View.generateViewId();
    icoView.setId(idGen);
    icoView.setTag("icon_"+getDrawables);
    gridlayout.setColumnCount(6);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
Adding `new drawables` but with less resolution and using there for my stickers' selector. Using [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) as a Recycler I only reduce 500MB of RAM usage. 
Another way I see is converting drawables to bitmaps and then set a resize to the bitmaps.

Answer (score 2):

Do not add so many ImageViews to your layout. They wont be visible all at once anyways i assume. Use something like a [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) or a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) that manages the recycling of views for you.

Comment: Can you send me a link or something to get reference about this?

Comment: This gives me the same problem with ram (I try GridView), not solved... 
`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.rogerrv.fillthem, PID: 3723
                  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 7225356 byte allocation with 3387472 free bytes and 3MB until OOM
                      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                      ....`

Comment: Did you create an adapter for your images and bound it via `setAdapter()`?

Comment: Yes, I use an adapter it is because of the drawable size

Comment: Do you instantiate all ImageViews at once? Always use the convertView and fill the existing image views with the new content.